# Crankery: Is there a perfect inner model of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

In the book "Aspects of Vagueness", the article "The alternative set theory and its approach to Cantor's set theory" by A. Sochor proposes the following definition:

> We will say that a set universe is perfect if for each $X$ lying in it, each actualizable subset of $X$ also lies in it.

Later in the book, it is suggested that no ZFC set universe can be perfect:

> With the assumption that the power set of an infinite existing set was actualizable, mathematics entered a peculiar world. It is a world only in the sense of a fairy tale, in which we meet a large number of wondrous creatures in the form of fantastic topological spaces, algebraic structures and the like. The immortality of Cantor's theory of sets lies not in its truth but just in the opposite - in its fantasticness and its suggestivity, by which it came to captivate the mathematics of an entire epoch.

If I replace "actualizable" by element of an inner model of ZFC, I get the following defintion:

> We will say that an inner model $M$ of ZFC is perfect if for each $X\in M$, every subset $Y\subset X$ of $X$ also lies in $M$, i.e. $Y\in M$.

If A. Sochor had a valid point, then it should at least be possible to prove that "no inner model of ZFC can be perfect". This statement is not completely implausible, because [a model of a first order theory is not allowed to use a proper class as its domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269727/paradox-any-set-theory-without-universe-set-is-not-a-model-of-itself). So my question is on the one hand whether this statement is true, but I would also like to know whether this statement would have any relevance besides "pure" crankery against ZFC.

Comment: Of course only $V$ is perfect under this definition: If $V\setminus M$ is nonempty, take $Y$ in this difference, of least rank. Then all its elements are in $M$, so $Y$ is a subset of $M$, so it is a subset of a rank initial segment of $M$, which we can take as $X$. Were $M$ perfect, this would mean that $Y\in M$, contradiction.

Comment: As for whether this is "relevant", at least the *argument* I used is standard. It is part of what we use to show that any elementary embedding $j:V\to M$ has a critical point.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I think Thomas Klimpel's notion of "inner model" does not require it to contain all the ordinals, since he write "a model ... is not allowed to use a proper class as its domain." Your first comment assumes that inner models are big, when you say that $Y$ has to be a subset of a rank initiial segment, rather than of all of $M$.  On (what I believe to be) Thomas's intended meaning, there can be perfect inner models, namely the rank initial segments of the universe up to an inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Sure, I am using inner model in the standard sense, which seems different from Thomas's use, thanks for pointing this out. In his sense, where we allow $M$ to be a set, the perfect inner models are precisely the $V_\kappa$ that model $\mathsf{ZFC}$. (You do not need $\kappa$ inaccessible.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass My intention was to use the notion of "inner model" in the usual sense. I was aware that there are additional requirements for inner models, like being transitive, but didn't look up all requirements in detail. The general intention of the question was to turn the statement from A. Sochor into a precise mathematical statement which can be analyzed with mathematical rigor.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks for the correction about inaccessibility.  If my comment were still editable, I'd change "namely" to "for example".

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel Since you intend to use "inner model" in its currently standard sense, which requires the model to contain all the ordinals, then you should be aware that inner models are not models in the sense of the statement you quoted, "a model ... is not allowed to use a proper class as its domain." To contain all ordinals, the domain of an inner model has to be a proper class.

Comment: It might be useful to note that the set-vs.-class distinction is quite different in the alternative set theory from what we are used to in theories like Neumann-Bernays-Gödel or Morse-Kelley. In particular, in the alternative set theory a subclass of a set need not be a set. Rather than being "too big" (as in NBG or MK), such classes are regarded as "too vaguely defined". Also, in view of the title of this question, I should point out that the alternative set theory is serious mathematics, not crankery, even though some of the surrounding propaganda looks suspicious.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I also noted that the "detailed requirements" for inner models imply that they are "proper classes". This is more than just a detail, because the model theory I have learned so far assumed the domain to be a set. It's not obvious to me how much this changes things, or how it is intended to be interpreted. I'm unsure whether this means that we are actually using NBG instead of ZFC (so that we can talk about proper classes), or whether it just means that there is another ZFC meta-universe, in which both the model and its inner model live. I will first have to work this out for me..